# The Fragment refreshes on back- Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am making an application using the Android Navigation component. But I ran into a very fundamental problem which can cause problems in the whole development of my application.

**The Scenario**

I have this Fragment where in `onViewCreated` I am observing a field from my viewmodel.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventDetailsViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.init(context!!,eventId)

    viewModel.onEventDetailsUpdated().observe(this, Observer {
        setEventDetails(it)
    })

}
```

And in the `setEventDetails` method, I set recyclerviews with the data.

**The PROBLEM**

This fragment is a long fragment with a scroll. Suppose I scroll long way down to a section and click on a button which takes me to another fragment.

But when I come back to this fragment, it again takes me to the top and does everything that it did on first load.
That can be troubling. It is kind of recreating the whole fragment instead of keeping its old state.

**What I tried**

I searched a lot of questions. And went through [This Github Query](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/419), [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553333/navigation-component-prevent-to-recreate-fragment-on-back-press), [Another Git](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/530)... But I could not solve my problem.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are replacing fragment or just adding

Comment: Naive solution : Try saving current scollY in viewmodel in on pause and scroll to saved scrollY in onResume

Comment: @NehaRathore I am using android's jetpack navigation component, so I am calling `findNavController().navigate` method. I am not using the fragment manager

Comment: @TheBat have you got the solution? Am also stuck in same problem, am also using NavController.

Comment: @AbdulRafay have you found any solution about it ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Fragment's view will get destroyed whenever you navigate forward to another fragment.

RecyclerView's scroll position should be automatically restored, even when new instance of RecyclerView is created and new Adapter instance is set, as long as you setup everything with the same dataset as before. Also, you need to do it before the first layout pass.

This means that you need your old data and you need to have it ready immediately (no async loads!).
ViewModelProvider should return the same ViewModel instance. That ViewModel holds the data you should be able to synchronously get and display on the UI. Make sure to refactor your viewModel.init method - you don't want to make API call if data is already there in case when going back. A simple boolean `isInitialized` can work here, or you can even check if LiveData is empty or not.

Also, you have a subtle bug when calling `observe` on `LiveData`. onViewCreated can be called many times for the same fragment (each time you navigate forward and back!) - so `observe` will be called each time. Your Fragment will be subscribed many times to the same `LiveData`. This means you will get events multiple times (once for each subscription). This can cause issues with RecyclerView state restoration too. Your subscription is tied to Lifecycle owner you passed. You passed Fragment's Lifecycle owner which is tied to Fragment's lifecycle. What you want to do is pass Fragment view's lifecycle owner, so whenever the view is destroyed the subscription gets cleared, and you only have 1 subscription ever and only while the Fragment's view is alive. For this, you can use `getViewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rely on ViewModel to restore the fragment state because ViewModel doesn't get destroyed on fragment change.
In your viewModel, create a variable listState

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var listState: Parcelable? = null
}
```

Then in your fragment use below code

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by navGraphViewModels<HomeViewModel>(R.id.mobile_navigation)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        if (viewModel.listState != null) {
            list.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(viewModel.listState)
            viewModel.listState = null
        }else{
           //load data normally
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewModel.listState = list.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the same code in java I'm stuck with the same issue and every solution I find is in kotlin.

Comment: When I call viewModel.listState = list.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState(), list variable is null because onSaveInstanceState() returns null

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to initialize the view model each time. Just check for null before initializing. Don't know kotlin, still it will be something like:

```
if(viewModel == null){
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventDetailsViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.init(context!!,eventId)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try putting this code where you first call your fragment.

```
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, yourSearchFragment, "searchFragment");
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft.commit();
```

and this when going back to the fragment

```
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("searchFragment"));
 ft.add(R.id.main_fragment, yourDetailfragment);
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft.commit();
```

Comment: I am using android's jetpack navigation component, so I am calling findNavController().navigate method. I am not using the fragment manager